# Помогите разобраться с ImportXml

Tags: парсер, xpath, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

**Дано:** https://pub.fsa.gov.ru/rds/declaration/view/14707440/applicant 

**Задача:** вывести номер телефона в гугл таблицу с помощью функции ImportXML

 **Проблема:** не могу правильно написать запрос_xpath (на номер телефона) постоянно выдает ошибку н/д 

Помогите решить проблему в таком виде **IMPORTXML(ссылка; запрос_xpath)** и пожалуйста проверьте на работоспособность. Спасибо!

Comment: А вы свой запрос предоставьте сначала:)

Comment: IMPORTXML("https://pub.fsa.gov.ru/rds/declaration/view/14707440/applicant";"/html/body/fgis-root/div/fgis-rds-view-declaration/div/div/div/div/fgis-rds-view-application-applicant/fgis-card-block-wrapper/fgis-card-block/div/div[2]/div/fgis-rds-view-contacts/fgis-card-row-spoiler/div[2]/fgis-card-edit-row-two-columns/fgis-card-info-row[1]/div[2]/p")